# How to receive multiple websocket responses send in sequence, for a single request sent, using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to setup a performance test for a websocket application, using **JMeter**.
The request is `{"type":"subscribe_rq","id":1,"ts":"2018-10-16T00:00:00","data":{"sinceSeq":0}}`.
Response is multipart and sequential; initial response and an update every second, as long as the connection is open. (I checked this with "WebSocket Test Client", a chrome extension).
Currently, I only get the first main response, but not the updates. Rather not sure how to get these updates. How to achieve this in JMeter? That is, how to keep the connection open for a specified period (say 5 secs) and receive the multiple responses during that period and assert it?
To keep the connection open I have a Constant Timer with 5 secs in **Thread Delay**. Not sure if this will work...

Comment: Which (JMeter) WebSocket plugin are you using?

Comment: @Peter, I've been trying to use both "JMeter WebSocket Sampler by Maciej Zaleski" and now  "JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch". So far have not figured how to use them in above situation.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward please remember to include essential parts of your query into the question itself, i.e. output from the "Network" tab of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or screenshot of this `WebSocket Test Client` (whatever it is) could tell the full story.

In the mean time, there is a project: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) which has many useful [sample JMeter Test Plans](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/af14726bbe017ff2b4228222b259c5cde2da46d7/samples?at=master) including the one which you can use as the basis: [Single read sample.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/af14726bbe017ff2b4228222b259c5cde2da46d7/samples/Single%20read%20sample.jmx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) which queries the data in the loop over the single WebSocket Connection.

Check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) article to get started with the WebSocket Samplers.

Comment: @Dimitri T, I took a look and will try this out.

Comment: It sort of worked. I'm still not sure how to make all the connections wait for a specified number of seconds and close them, while still messages are coming in. Instead, I used another plugin, which seem to work.

Comment: Using above as the temp. solution, it's not supported anymore by the author. WIth Peter D.'s plugin when I tried to close connection while more messages being sent in, it gives an error.   Thread Name: Thread Group 1-25
Sample Start: 2019-01-10 09:06:05 EST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Sent bytes:31
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: WebSocket error: unsuccesful close.
Response message: WebSocket error: received not a close frame, but Text frame with text

Comment: @user10829672, "I used another plugin, which seem to work." Can you share the other plugin that worked. i have same usecase.